# Displaying only a determined range of data

Tags: vba, excel

I want to display to the user certain information that exists on a separated worksheet, whenever he clicks a button.

I can set Excel to "go" to this worksheet at the starting line of the range , but I could not find a way to hide everything else.

Is there some method for this, or do I have to hide all rows and columns?

Comment: You need to put the data in a new empty sheet or you want to hide everything exept the data in the existing sheet?

Comment: I understand that was dubious - I want to hide everything else.

Comment: Of if possible, show it in some form of popup - msgbox doesn't cut it.

Comment: so, ideally you'd like this info to popup instantly, without switching any sheets or workbooks - so as to not disrupt workflow, right? If so, then I think that a custom userform might be best for something like this.

Comment: I've never used it, is there any way to show tabular data in a custom userform?

Comment: Yes, there is. Right-click the workbook vba project and `Insert -> UserForm`.

Comment: But I woudn't know if VBA has some grid or table control to use.

Comment: On the user form, create a listbox, and then you should be able to do this by linking the listbox to the worksheet range.

Comment: A list would show only an unformatted column of values. Maybe I can copy the range and paste in the userform as a picture.

Comment: Yes there's a way to do it with an exported image file. It's a little trickier I think, and noticeably slower since the image export method takes a few seconds, in my experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert a UserForm in the Workbook's VB Project.

Add a ListBox control to the userform.

Then do something like this code in the `UserForm_Activate` event code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Dim tbl As Range

Set tbl = Range("B2:E7")  '## Change this to capture the rang you need '

Me.Caption = "Displaying data from " & _
    ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & tbl.Address

With ListBox1

    .ColumnHeads = False
    .ColumnCount = tbl.Columns.Count
    .RowSource = tbl.Address
End With

End Sub
```

Which gives unformatted data from the range:

[image: Screenshot of table linked to userform]

Comment: Thanks. I'm having some trouble trying to autosize columns though.

Comment: columns in the userform? these can be resized with VBA but I don't know the exact code off te top of my head. If you play around with this subroutine and the Locals window a little bit, create some variables to iterate over .columns.count and manipulate their widths as needed.

Answer (score 2):

To export the range as an image, you could create an Image in the UserForm instead of a Listbox.  Then this should be enough to get you started.

[image: Screenshot of image in UserForm]

As you can see from this screenshot, the image might not always come out very clearly. Also, if you are working with a large range of cells, the image might not fit on your userform, etc.  I will leave figuring that part out up to you :)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Dim tbl As Range
Dim imgPath As String

Set tbl = Range("B2:E7")  '## Change this to capture the rang you need '

imgPath = Export_Range_Images(tbl)

Caption = "Displaying data from " & _
    ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & tbl.Address

With Image1
    If Not imgPath = vbNullString Then
        .Picture = LoadPicture(imgPath)
        .PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeClip
        .PictureAlignment = 2 'Center
        .PictureTiling = False
        .SpecialEffect = 2 'Sunken
    End If
End With

End Sub


Function Export_Range_Images(rng As Range) As String
'## Modified by David Zemens with
'   credit to: _
'   http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-save-excel-range-as-image-using.html ##'


Dim ocht As Object
Dim srs As Series

rng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture

ActiveSheet.Paste
Set ocht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart
For Each srs In ocht.Chart.SeriesCollection
    srs.Delete
Next

'## Modify this line as needed ##'
fname = "C:\users\david_zemens\desktop\picture.jpg"

On Error Resume Next
Kill fname
On Error GoTo 0
ocht.Width = rng.Width
ocht.Height = rng.Height
ocht.Chart.Paste

ocht.Chart.Export Filename:=fname, FilterName:="JPG"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ocht.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set ocht = Nothing

Export_Range_Images = fname

End Function
```

Comment: I get an "Automation error" on `ocht.Chart.Export Filename:=fname, FilterName:="JPG"` , any idea?

Comment: Nope. What version of Excel are you using? This code executes fine for me in Excel 2010 Win 7 64b. Modified slightly from some code that I use routinely to show images in userforms in PowerPoint, where the same method works...

Comment: Ok I got it - the path I was using did not work for some reason (C:\\).

Comment: That was my first guess but I'd expect a different error `Runtime error 76 path not found` if the filepath is wrong. Glad you got it figured out!  As always, if this has been helpful, please consider upvoting it, or if it has solved your problem please consider marking it as "accepted" answer.  Cheers.

Comment: Sure, I'm just going through the code - right now an error on `srs.Delete`

Comment: you're going to have to provide more information than "an error". As I've noted previously, I am running this without any error, so, please indicate what error message or provide a screenshot if possible.

Comment: Yeah - (translated) message is smth like `Method 'Delete' for object 'Series' has failed` .

Comment: Put a breakpoint before that line and then in debugger window do `?ocht.Chart.SeriesCollection.Count`

Answer (score 0):

If you `record a macro` and hide some columns and rows manually, the code will be produced for you, and you will see how it's done.

Comment: Macro recording produces a lot of bad code.  In this instance, it will cause the screen to switch to the sheet we want hidden before hiding the rows, showing the user for a moment exactly what we are trying to hide from them.

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore macro recording serves a great purpose of exposing nearly every action -- to a fault. It is then up to the developer to remove the "bad" or undesired code, and tailor the recorded code to fit his/her exact needs.

Comment: Well, since the author could get to the range he likes, I assume he understands enough to chose the code he needs.